# Is there a Latin word for "dune"?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

Did the Romans have a word for "dune", as in sand dunes? There are plenty of words relating to sand itself, but I can't find anything specifically about dunes. There is a placed called [Arenae Montes](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Arenae%20Montes) (sand hills) which seems to refer to a specific location, although that name certainly seems to mean something like "sand dunes". Could that be used as a common noun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that all Romance languages (even Romanian) have borrowed forms of the Germanic "dune" suggests that the Romans did not have a word for it.